# Regex to match all backslash characters, except new line, carriage return, etc

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm looking for a regex to escape all backslash characters into double blackshash characters, except for newlines, carriage returns, etc..

This function:

```
Public Function EscapeInvalidCharacters(ByVal str As String) As String
    str = str.Replace("\", "\\")            ' Backslash

    str = str.Replace("'", "\'")            ' Single quote
    str = str.Replace("""", "\""")          ' Double quote
    str = str.Replace(vbNewLine, "\n")      ' New line
    str = str.Replace(vbCr, "\r")           ' Carriage return
    str = str.Replace(vbTab, "\t")          ' Horizontal tab
    str = str.Replace(vbBack, "\b")         ' Backspace
    str = str.Replace(vbFormFeed, "\f")     ' Form feed

    Return str
End Function
```

with this input:

```
"This is a test.\nThis is another test.\n"
```

Wrongly, generates the following output:

```
"This is a test.\\nThis is another test.\\n"
```

Is it possible to alter the line `str = str.Replace("\", "\\")` so that it doesn't alter the newlines?

Answer (score 4):

```
\(?!r|n|t|b|f)
```

Try this.This should do it

Comment: Running this `Regex.Replace(str, "\(?!r|n|t|b|f)", "\\")`  gave me an argument exception.

Comment: @bastos.sergio is `\n` is a literal `\n` ?

Comment: @ Avinash Raj all instances of `\n` should be treated as a literal.

Comment: @vks same error. The message, after doing a rough translating back to english, is "parsing "\(?!n)" - Too many )"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to vks, I came up with this solution:

```
Public Function EscapeInvalidCharacters(ByVal str As String) As String
    'str = str.Replace("\", "\\")           ' Backslash
    str = Regex.Replace(str, "\\(?!n|r|t|b|f)", "\\")' Backslash

    str = str.Replace("'", "\'")            ' Single quote
    str = str.Replace("""", "\""")          ' Double quote
    str = str.Replace(vbNewLine, "\n")      ' New line
    str = str.Replace(vbCr, "\r")           ' Carriage return
    str = str.Replace(vbTab, "\t")          ' Horizontal tab
    str = str.Replace(vbBack, "\b")         ' Backspace
    str = str.Replace(vbFormFeed, "\f")     ' Form feed

    Return str
End Function
```